# Postgres jsonb : cast array element to integer

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Using Postgres 11.2.9 (ubuntu),

In my database, I have a jsonb field containing values that look like this :
`[1618171589133, 1618171589245, 1618171589689]`

I'd like to retrieve rows where the first element is lower than a specific value. I've tried this :

`SELECT * FROM user.times WHERE time ->> 0 < 1618171589133`

but I get the following error : `ERROR: operator does not exist: text = bigint`

Should I somehow cast the time value to numeric value ? I've tried `time ->> 0::numeric` but I actually don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried `time -> 0 < 1618171589133` ? A look here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html makes it look like `->>` intentionally returns text instead of a numeric value

Comment: @GSP fair point, however I think I'd still have to cast it as bigint, `time -> 0 < 1618171589133` returns an error `operator does not exist: jsonb <= bigint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->>` operator returns the element at given position as text, which you can then convert to integer (or as it seems in this case, bigint), as you would normally do in postgres, using the `::` as suffix.

```
SELECT * FROM user.times WHERE ((time ->> 0)::bigint) < 1618171589133
```

Comment: To expand on why this works, `::` binds tighter than `->>`, so his original code was casting just 0 to numeric, and then using numeric 0 to index into the jsonb.